# How to check if some number is in_array in PhalconPHP volt?

Tags: arrays, phalcon, volt

I am looking for a in_array function equivalency in volt.
Is there another way to do this?

```
{% for modelObj in modelList %}

  {% if modelObj.getId() in modelIdCheckedList %}
    {{ check_field('id[]', 'value':modelObj.id, 'checked': true) }}
  {% else %}
    {{ check_field('id[]', 'value':modelObj.id, 'checked': null) }}
  {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

I need to do something like this

```
{{ check_field('id[]', 'value':modelObj.id, 'checked': in_array(modelObj.getId(), modelIdCheckedList )) }}
```

Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can achieve this.

### Using a Function

Register the `in_array` as a function that Volt will understand. In your Volt registration you need to add the function to the compiler as follows:

```
$volt = new Phalcon\Mvc\View\Engine\Volt($view, $diContainer);
$volt->setOptions( .... );
$volt->getCompiler()->addFunction(
    'in_array',
    function ($parameters) {
        return 'in_array(' . $parameters . ')';
    }
);
```

### Using an Extension

You can also register a PHP function extension, which will allow all PHP functions to work in Volt.

Create your extension class

```
class PhpFunctionExtension
{
    /**
     * This method is called on any attempt to compile a function call
     */
    public function compileFunction($name, $arguments)
    {
        if (function_exists($name)) {
            return $name . "(". $arguments . ")";
        }
    }
}
```

Register it in the Volt compiler

```
$volt = new Phalcon\Mvc\View\Engine\Volt($view, $diContainer);
$volt->setOptions( .... );
$volt->getCompiler()->addExtension(new PhpFunctionExtension());
```

https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/volt.html#extending-volt
https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/volt.html#extensions

Answer (score 0):

Use the `in` operator:

```
{{ modelObj.getId() in modelIdCheckedList }}
```

So you may do something like:

```
{{ check_field('id[]', 'value': modelObj.id, 'checked': modelObj.getId() in modelIdCheckedList }}
```

Source: [Volt - Other Operators](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/3.3/volt#expressions-other-operators)